# Indication of deleted comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

In the comment section of quesions or answers when a previous comment is deleted there should be an indication of the deleted comment where the comment used to be. Now it's hard to follow an exchange of comments if the comment a new comment is referring to is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

In that situation you should flag the comment / post itself to state that is unclear and one of the mods can either:

a) remove that comment
b) reinstate the deleted comment

They're not really for ongoing discussions anyway, plus comments get flagged *a lot* so it's often easier for the mods to just delete the flagged ones if they look like they're not much use instead of having to go to the post and read through all the comments on all the posts trying to decide whether they're useful or not.

But comments can be undeleted if necessary.

Comment: Ok, I just think a one row note indicating that once there was a comment here and now it's gone would reduce both confusion and leg work.

Comment: You would be surprised how many comments get deleted. It would look quite a mess to show such indicators (And I would know - as a moderator we already get to see such messages, and it can look quite messy!)

Comment: ahaa, well, I guess I wouldn't know about that. Ok, then I have a good explanation of why it works the way it does!

Comment: @JonW - I've had comments deleted and I have no idea why. And sometimes it affects the flow of other comments. Example in the link shown below I wrote the first comment to the question and now it's disappeared!? Of course I may be going crazy but that's another story.  http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/67217/ways-for-a-company-to-organize-common-shared-icons-images-and-graphics

Comment: @Mayo You do have a deleted comment on that post. It was: "*This is a good question. I hope there is a good answer. –  Mayo Nov 3 at 19:20"*. That is typical of the comments that get removed. Comments are for requesting clarification or critiquing posts; comments such as this one are just glorified "+1" type posts which are noise and unnecessary - that is what the Upvote button is for. If everyone left "+1" comments the posts would be awash with them, and they bring no benefit to anyone reading the questions. Show your appreciation of posts by upvoting. That actually rewards the poster rep.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll keep that in mind. FWIW - I did upvote the original poster as well.

Comment: @Mayo (and anyone else reading this) For reference: [Here is some general comment advice from Stack Exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)